# Перенос web dynamic project на maven

Tags: maven, java, tomcat

Пытаюсь перенести проект на мавен. Структуру каталогов использую дефолтную, в pom описываю только зависимости. Проект компилитcя успешно, но при запуске на tomcat все время получаю следующие [ексепшны](http://paste.ubuntu.com/798208/) и listener соответственно не стартует.

Настройки context.xml для tomcat не менялись. Да и код тоже. До попытки переноса приложения на мавен все запускалось и работало. Может для мавена нужна какая-то отдельная настройка для работы с jdbc? Пыталась пересоздать проект и подложить туда свои исходники - результат тот же.

Comment: Ну так понятное дело.. сообщение об ошибке однозначно указывать на то, что нет соответствующего ресурса. Как вы раньше запускали ваш проект? Каким образом вы прописывали эти ресурсы? Вы же не ожидаете, что они святым духом появятся в веб-контейнере.

Comment: Вы, видимо, потеряли файл (напр., mysqldb.xml или datatsource.xml) или же секцию конфигуационного файла (напр. web.xml) с описанием вашей БД. погуглите "datasource.xml tomcat"

Comment: @kisuxa, не забудьте принять верный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть, дело в classloader'e maven'a и tomcat'a. Проблема может возникнуть из-за того, что при запуске депенденси подгружаются в разном порядке. Не знаю, как томкэт загружает жарки, мавен их грузит в том порядке, в каком они указаны в помке. Дело в том, что какая-то депенденси может за собой тянуть зависящую другой версии, чем у Вас она указана в пом-файле, и, соответственно, кто первее загрузился, тот класс и будет использоваться.

Хотя из стектрейса могу сказать, что Вам надо смотреть на то место, где датасорс добавляется в jndi. Видимо, вы хотите стартануть томкат через мавеновский плагин, а раньше сервер стартавал отдельно, и где-то в нем был конфиг файл для jndi. А при старте через плагин этот конфиг не подтягивается.

Comment: Вы оказались абсолютно правы. Томкат просто не видел файл конфига jndi. Полечила, указав в поме путь к ресурсу:

    <build>
      <plugins>
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
         <webResources>
          <resource>
           <directory>resource2</directory>
          </resource>
         </webResources>
        </configuration>
       </plugin>
      </plugins>
     </build>

Comment: Ставим галочку, если вопрос решён.